# What does this symbol mean in commutative algebra?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, commutative-algebra

(Algebraic Geometry and commutative algebra - Bosch - page 16)

I could not find the  symbol in the glossary at the end of the book. What does it mean ?

[image]

I cannot see it in my reference manual either (Commutative Algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry - Eisenbud)

Comment: I suspect the symbol denotes a [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct).

Comment: As for the latex-symbol, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126166/product-coproduct-sign).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the disjoint union from set theory. Each element of $\text{Spec } R$ maps into a different set from the disjoint union.

In category theory this symbol can sometimes be a coproduct, but in this situation it’s not.

Added: Of course disjoint union is the coprduct in sets, but you hardly see all those rings/ $R$-modules and think “category of sets”. This tradition of confusing young scholars of scheme theory goes back, at least to Hartshorne’s book.